# Can i run two copies of a python program?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a python script called `scr.py`. Running `python scr.py` creates a `scr.pyc` file which is interpreted by Python. Now, let's say I make a change in `scr.py` while it is running, and then in another terminal window, I run `python scr.py` again. What happens? Does the original `scr.pyc` file get overwritten? Are there any problems that might occur? Could you run two slightly different copies of the same file at the same time?

Comment: Are you asking for curiosity or is there a problem you are facing (for example, the script is taking a long time so you want to run it in parallel, by changing some things); or is the case that its a web application and you want to modify it without shutting down the server?

Comment: Seems similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186600/modify-a-running-python-program).

Comment: Try it first with some simple code snippet and let us know what you got. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will try to overwrite .pyc file with the new version. But this won't affect the first program unless explicit module reload is called, in it because the module is loaded into memory.

OTOH, for example, printing stack for an exception needs reading source file, and, if it's changed, wrong lines will be printed. So this replacing on the fly is recommended only when module is properly reloaded just after this.